# How to count the number of characters in each line of a file, excluding a list of specific characters?

Tags: bash

How can I count how many characters appear within a file, minus those from a specific list. Here is an example file:

```
你好吗？
我很好，你呢？
我也很好。
```

I want to exclude any occurrences of `？`, `，`, and `。` from the count. The output would look like this:

```
3
5
4
```

Answer (score 3):

A pure bash solution:

```
while IFS= read -r l; do
    l=${l//[？，。]/}
    echo "${#l}"
done < file
```

Answer (score 2):

Try

```
sed 's/[，。？]//g' file | perl -C -nle 'print length'
```

The `sed` part removes unwanted characters, and the `perl` part counts the remaining characters.

Comment: We both used `perl`, but on the opposite sides of the pipeline

Comment: yep. The only problem is I am not very sure of how perl handles unicode. Not an expert in perl.

Comment: Piping `sed` to `perl` feels very redundant. `perl -CAS -nle 's/[，。？]//g; print length'` does the trick.

Comment: It probably is for perl pros. But from the point of view of a perl newbie, sed+minimum perl will be less intimidating.

Comment: Except that the Perl substitution looks *exactly* like the `sed` substitution. See my comment on jordanm's answer.

Answer (score 2):

One way is to remove those characters from the stream and then use `wc -m`. Here is an example that uses perl to remove the characters:

```
perl -pe 's/(\？|,|，|。)//g' file.txt | \ 
  while read -r line; do 
    printf "$line" | wc -m ; 
  done
```

Comment: `perl -lne 's/[？,，。]//g; print length`

Answer (score 2):

or more simple:

```
tr -d [？,，。] <file | wc -m
```

Answer (score 1):

A simple solution, approached to [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19994778/2353900), but using `awk`:

```
sed 's/[？，。]//g' file | awk '{ print length($0) }'
```

Comment: Awk can do that substitution - no need for `sed`. `awk '{gsub("[？，。]", ""); print length()}'`